# Debugging Nuxt.js application (client side) with Chrome developer console

Tags: javascript, vue.js, debugging, webpack, nuxt.js

When I'm trying to debug a Nuxt.js application (the client side code, not the server side) in Chrome, I'm finding that breakpoints aren't being hit when I expect them to be.

in `nuxt.config.js` I have the following webpack config:

```
extend (config, ctx) {
  if (ctx.isDev) {
    config.devtool = ctx.isClient ? 'source-map' : 'inline-source-map'
  }
}
```

In a component (`login/index.vue`) I have the following method:

```
methods: {
    login() {
        // in the chrome developer console I can see that this logs, but setting a breakpoint on the below line,
        // it tends to not always stop/"break" at this point
        console.log("at login/index.vue")
        this.$store.dispatch('login',
            this.credentials
        ).then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            this.$router.push({
                name: 'index'
            })
        }).catch(e => {
            console.log(e.message)
        })
    }
}
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with how webpack loads files. In the Chrome developer console I can see this:

[image: filesystem]

I have tried setting breakpoints in `webpack://pages/login/index.vue` as this is the only file that is showing the development style code (the rest of the files like `index.vue?56ff` are showing the interpreted versions/updates I suppose).

There end up being multiple `pages/login/index.vue` files as you can see in the screenshot above. What is webpack doing, and how can I reliably set breakpoints when debugging the client side of Nuxt.js applications? I can see that breakpoints are reliably hit in the Vuex store, but tend to be skipped in the `pages/` components.

Maybe I'm using the wrong type of source map for client side debugging?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? Or a reason why so many versions of files show up in the Sources pane?